# Getting Partial Fraction Decomposition Wrong

Tags: partial-fractions

So I have done this solution:
[image: Wrong Partial Fraction Decomposition]

But it's wrong according to technology. I fail to see any error I've made in this solution, do you guys have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: In the line starting with $0s^3$, you didn't distribute $As^2(s + 1)$ and $Bs(s + 1)$ properly - instead of $A$ and $B$, you want $As^2$ and $Bs$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fourth line you have, $As^3 +A$ and $Bs^2 + B$ but you should have
$As^3 +As^2$ and $Bs^2 + Bs$

Comment: This is the correct answer. Thank you, I'm the king of algebra mistakes. I'll mark it when this website lets me.

Answer (score 1):

4th equal sign. You did not distribute the $s^2$ and so on. It should have been

$$As^3+As^2...$$